# J'ai un master en X, et j'ai fait des études par moi même en Y, comment décrire ça dans l'introduction?

Tags: expressions, formulation-idiomatique

J'ai un master dans une spécialité X. Ensuite j'ai passé deux ans à apprendre une autre spécialité Y moi-même. Maintenant, j'aimerais postuler pour un travail qui exige une connaissance dans le domaine Y, et j'ai besoin d'écrire une lettre de motivation. Voici l'introduction que j'ai écrite :

> Titulaire d'un master en X, et ayant fait des études en Y, j'ai le plaisir de candidater pour le poste [Nom de Poste] au sein de votre établissement.

Qu'est ce que vous en pensez ? Est-ce qu'il y a des erreurs, ou est-ce qu'il y a une meilleure méthode pour écrire l'introduction ?

Comment: Ça dépend de ce qui *faire les études par moi-même* vraiment signifie: prendre un cours et/ou passer une certification ? - dans ce cas on a le document à montrer, au même titre comme le diplôme de master. Simplement avoir travaillé dans le domaine ? - dans ce cas on affiche son expérience, soutenu par des lettres de la recommandation, par exemple. Si j'ai étudié quelques chose moi-même, sans preuve, je ne le mettrais pas en CV, sauf si la connaissance acquise est évidente - e.g., je parle français.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vous pouvez très bien mentionner vos études personnelles dans une demande d'emploi à conditions qu'elles aient été sérieuses. Il a existé au cours des siècles passés de nombreux autodidactes qui ne sont jamais passés par les écoles et qui ont été conduits au succès par leurs  études personnelles ; l'un des plus fameux, peut-être aura été [Thomas Edison](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison) ; [Frédéric Chopin](https://www.radiofrance.fr/franceculture/podcasts/les-nuits-de-france-culture/veronique-puchala-chopin-etait-un-pianiste-completement-autodidacte-6776417) était un pianiste autodidacte ; voilà un autre autodidacte, un de nos contemporains celui-ci, [Claude Loirand](https://www.ouest-france.fr/pays-de-la-loire/reze-44400/reze-claude-loirand-un-inventeur-hors-pair-6918653), qui dans le domaine de la technologie a récemment acquis 6 brevets grâce à ses études personnelles. Il n'y a pas à avoir de scrupules donc à mentionner des études que l'on a menées soi-même.

- Titulaire d'un master en X, et ayant fait des études en autodidacte dans le domaine de Y, …
- Titulaire d'un master en X, et ayant appris le/la Y en autodidacte Y, …

[études en autodidacte](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A9tudes%20en%20autodidacte%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

[appris en autodidacte](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22appris%20en%20autodidacte%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Tôt ou tard vous aurez à expliquer comment vous avez acquis vos connaissances ; la manière plus directe de les justifier au début me semble préférable ; on ne vous soupçonne pas ainsi plus tard d'avoir essayé de dissimuler un manque de diplômes par des formules vagues.

Comment: votre réponse est très intéressante, je vous en remercie!

Answer (score 2):

"Faire des études en Y" implique en général d'avoir suivi des cours officiels dans l'enseignement supérieur.

Je dirais plutôt

> ayant acquis de l'expérience sur Y

> ayant acquis des connaissances en Y

> ayant etudié/exploré Y de manière approfondie

Comment: Merci beaucoup Guillaume pour votre réponse!